# Upgrading from Gnome 3.36.2 to 3.36.3

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and noticed that I'm running Gnome 3.36.2 - when the latest stable release is 3.36.3. How can I upgrade? Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3.36.3 is already in focal-proposed (testing). When it reaches focal-updates, your system will offer you the upgrade.

- You can see for yourself using the very handy `rmadison` command, provided by the `devscripts` package:

  ```
  $ rmadison gnome-shell | grep focal
   gnome-shell | 3.36.1-5ubuntu1                   | focal                   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
   gnome-shell | 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1           | focal-updates           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
   gnome-shell | 3.36.3-1ubuntu1~20.04.2           | focal-proposed          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
  ```